# Does an array contain a specific item?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I recently starting learning JS so a beginner level answer would be great! Thanks.

```
function contains(arr, item) {
   // check to see if item is inside of arr
   // return true if it is, otherwise return false

}
```

Comment: `return arr.includes(item)`

Comment: [.includes()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) and [.find()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find)

Answer (score 0):

What about something like this?

```
const arr = [1,2,3];
const el = 2;
console.log(arr.includes(el)) // true
```